# pass Sample Command Line Parameters in the format -h name in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am writing a Java client program for MQ client to perform the initial test for that I need to pass the below parameters as below:
Sample Command Line Parameters
//  `-h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c CLIENT.CHANNEL -m A1 -q TEST.QUEUE` in eclipse.
I got `IllegalArgumentException` when I passed the values in program arguments in eclipse.how to pass the above parameters  Please help me on this.

MY code:

```
private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
}

...

params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
        params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
    }
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

if (allParamsPresent()) {
    qMgrName = (String) params.get("-m");
    System.out.println("qMgrName: " + qMgrName);
    outputQName = (String) params.get("-q");
    System.out.println("outputQName: " + outputQName);
    replytoQueueName = (String) params.get("-r");
    System.out.println("replytoQueueName: " + replytoQueueName);
    url = (String) params.get("-j");
    System.out.println("url: " + url);
    username = (String) params.get("-u");
    System.out.println("username: " + username);
    password = (String) params.get("-pp");
    System.out.println("password: " + password);
```

Comment: how did you pass the arguments in eclipse ? I did it and its working. I am able to retrieve the arguments in console.

Comment: in the eclipse RunAs-Runconfiguarions and in the Arguments I passed as below -h test7 one below one order then I am able to retrieve atguments. Is this correct?
-p 1414
-c test5
-m test
-q test1
-r test3
-j hello
-u user
-pp password

Answer (score 0):

I too defined parameters in `RunAs-> RunConfiguration` and it's all working for me.

[image]

Is this the way you defined. ?

Comment: Yes but its not worked for me then I tried with one by one line means first -h 120.0.0.1 then press enter second line another arguments then it is working not given error why?